# mute command with database - discord.py

Tags: mysql, discord, discord.py

So I have a database that stores `only` mute info such as:

```
"
user's id,
user's server,
unmute_time(timestamp for the exact removal time of the "Muted" role)
"
```

This is so that in case the bot goes offline, when it comes back it would still unmute the user automatically(if eligible for the unmute of course)

what's the best method for checking those user when the bot goes online, I tried `on_ready` but people said it wouldn't be the best(and assuming using a `while loop` until every user is unmuted will limit users!)

What's the best way to accomplish this?
thanks

Comment: I would run a background task every 60 secs to check whether the time has passed or not.

Comment: ooh, alright thanks!